# React Developer Tools for Chrome giving warning on minified assets

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

I have minified my resources using Gulp uglify plugin rather than using webpack's Uglify plugin as my application is getting bundled by gulp, But when I check react developer tools it is giving error **This page is using an unminified build of React** , but when i am checking chrome developer tools css and js is minified.

So can this be a bug in React developer tool? As the warning is quite misleading it seems to React developer tool is not checking the actual js or css file for minification, Also I have checked google page speed and it is stating that the assets are minified.

[image: This is the warning message]

[image: Minified js]

Comment: See this http://dev.topheman.com/make-your-react-production-minified-version-with-webpack/

Comment: Do I need to add webpackUglifyPlugin for production build even though I am setting process.env.NODE_ENV to production?

Comment: Yes you have to add uglify as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help !